# Try import java.util Cannot resolve symbol 'java'

Tags: java, maven

In IDEA IDE I met this problem. I tried to import java.util
[compiler setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suigc.png)

my pom.xml:

```java
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

Comment: Look under File > Project Structure > Project SDK and make sure you have a JDK selected.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out when I reboot my IDEA.
I think it is because I download new jdk jdk17.